# Combine columns in CSV file with Python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have a csv file with 3 columns. Using Python, I want to merge the data from column 3 into column 1 and delete column 3.

Example:

Here's what I have:

```
date, time, date
1/10, 5:30, 
    , 6:00, 1/10
1/11, 4:30, 
1/11, 5:00
```

Here's what I want:

```
date, time
1/10, 5:30 
1/10, 6:00
1/11, 4:30 
1/11, 5:00
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: When you say merge, do you mean overwrite if exists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service!

Comment: Do you only want to do this (in which case you could just use Excel), or is this intended to be a minor step in a larger program?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah, I can easily do this in excel, but trying to do it within a program in python

Comment: Then prepare for some fun times with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import csv

with open('in.csv') as infile, open('out.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader)  # Skip the header
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['date', 'time'])  # Write the header

    for row in reader:
        # Remove white spaces in each field and assign to vars
        date1, time, date2 = [x.strip() for x in row]
        writer.writerow([date1 or date2, time])
```

## Notes

- I opened the input and output files, create a CSV reader and writer from those files, respectively.
- For the reader, I skipped the header; for the writer, I write a new header. Simple operations.
- I assume that each line in the input always contain 3 fields: date1, time, and date2.
- The expression `date1 or date2` returns the non-empty string among the two of them.